# Where can I find when new version become available for Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, updates, repository, versions

For a number of packages that I use in Ubuntu Trusty Tahr I need a newer version than I can get via the default repositories. I often wonder when these new package versions get updated in the repository. Where I can find such information?

Answer (score 0):

You can find from **Ubuntu** official site http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: I did not mean ubuntu itself, but other software that can be insalled ia the default repositories Ubuntu offers.

Comment: @mmzc You would not normally recieve major software updates but only security patches, if you want new version of software you either have to find a third party repository or compite it yourself. Also, what newer software do you want and why exactly do you need it?

Comment: Really, does this mean that all software for a specific Ubuntu release will never get version updates? For example, I need Maxima, preferably the latest version. Here [link](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/maxima) I can find that the current version offered in trusty is 5.32.1-1. Does this mean this will never get updated untill the next Ubuntu release?